# Two random variables i.i.d and same distribution function, compute $P(X\leq Y|Y)$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I am struggling with the concept of regular conditional probability and conditional expectation, maybe someone can help me in order to have things more clear. I have two random variables X,Y i.i.d and same distribution function $F(t)$, and I have to compute $P(X\leq Y|Y)$... any idea? Thanks you so much in advance!

Comment: Use the following result: If $X$ is independent of $\mathcal F$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal F$ measurable, then for any (sufficiently nice) function $g$, one has $$E(g(X,Y)\mid \mathcal F) = \varphi(Y)$$, where $\varphi: y\mapsto E(g(X,y))$.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb P\left[X \le Y |Y\right]$ is the (random) probability of $X$ is smaller than $Y$ knowing the (random) value of $Y$. For instance if $X$ and $Y$ are independant, $$\mathbb P\left[X \le Y |Y\right] = F(Y)$$

Comment: This answer is not adequate, especially since the poster is asking about regular conditional probability.